# Form validation with AJAX, Jquery and PHP

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

How to use AJAX and Jquery to POST form written in HTML in order to validate with PHP?

Here is an example of what I got, I'm willing to get the error displayed and cookie value showed inline for editing without refreshing, can I somehow get it done with Jquery/AJAX?

Iv'e seen examples, think I should create another php page and post there the data but how should this done correctly with multiple form fields?

```
<?php
//check form submission
if(isset($_POST['send'])){

  //validation for Name
  if(strlen($_POST['fullname']) > 4){ 
    //set cookie if passed
    setcookie('fullname', $_POST['fullname']);
  }else {
    $error[] = 'Your name is required!';
  }
  //validation for ID
  if ((isset($_POST['id']) && is_numeric($_POST['id']))) {
    setcookie('id', $_POST['id']);
  }else {
     $error[] = 'ID number is required!';
  }    

//check for errors
  if(isset($error)){
    foreach($error as $error){
     echo '<p style="background: red;">'.$error.'</p>';
    }
  }
?>

<form method="post">
  <input name="fullname" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE["fullname"])){ 
  echo $_COOKIE["fullname"];} ?>" placeholder="full Name">
  <input name="id" type="text" value="<?php if(isset($_COOKIE["id"])){ 
  echo $_COOKIE["id"];} ?>" placeholder="ID">
  <input name="send" type="submit" value="send">
</form>
```

Comment: "*..I've seen examples, think I should create another php page and post there the data..*" Go Ahead. And, If problem comes, feel free to ask. But, First Try.

Comment: I can't see jquery anywhere in your code. Sure you can do it with ajax. But first of all you have to show your code with ajax what have you tried.

Comment: Please don't spam the SO . try to edit your previous post . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45408908/show-form-submitted-data-values-with-php-validation-without-refresh/45409219

Answer (score 1):

You can use below html, javascript and php code:

Here you can see complete information: [Click here](https://www.sanwebe.com/2011/12/making-simple-jquery-ajax-contact-form)

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="form-style" id="contact_form">
    <div class="form-style-heading">Please Contact Us</div>
    <div id="contact_results"></div>
    <div id="contact_body">
        <label><span>Name <span class="required">*</span></span>
            <input type="text" name="name" id="name" required="true" class="input-field"/>
        </label>
        <label><span>Email <span class="required">*</span></span>
            <input type="email" name="email" required="true" class="input-field"/>
        </label>
        <label><span>Phone</span>
            <input type="text" name="phone1" maxlength="4" placeholder="+91"  required="true" class="tel-number-field"/>&mdash;<input type="text" name="phone2" maxlength="15"  required="true" class="tel-number-field long" />
        </label>
            <label for="subject"><span>Regarding</span>
            <select name="subject" class="select-field">
            <option value="General Question">General Question</option>
            <option value="Advertise">Advertisement</option>
            <option value="Partnership">Partnership Oppertunity</option>
            </select>
        </label>
        <label for="field5"><span>Message <span class="required">*</span></span>
            <textarea name="message" id="message" class="textarea-field" required="true"></textarea>
        </label>
        <label>
            <span>&nbsp;</span><input type="submit" id="submit_btn" value="Submit" />
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

jQuery Ajax

```
<!-- include Google hosted jQuery Library -->
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Start jQuery code -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit_btn").click(function() { 

        var proceed = true;
        //simple validation at client's end
        //loop through each field and we simply change border color to red for invalid fields       
        $("#contact_form input[required=true], #contact_form textarea[required=true]").each(function(){
            $(this).css('border-color',''); 
            if(!$.trim($(this).val())){ //if this field is empty 
                $(this).css('border-color','red'); //change border color to red   
                proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag
            }
            //check invalid email
            var email_reg = /^([\w-\.]+@([\w-]+\.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$/; 
            if($(this).attr("type")=="email" && !email_reg.test($.trim($(this).val()))){
                $(this).css('border-color','red'); //change border color to red   
                proceed = false; //set do not proceed flag              
            }   
        });

        if(proceed) //everything looks good! proceed...
        {
            //get input field values data to be sent to server
            post_data = {
                'user_name'     : $('input[name=name]').val(), 
                'user_email'    : $('input[name=email]').val(), 
                'country_code'  : $('input[name=phone1]').val(), 
                'phone_number'  : $('input[name=phone2]').val(), 
                'subject'       : $('select[name=subject]').val(), 
                'msg'           : $('textarea[name=message]').val()
            };

            //Ajax post data to server
            $.post('contact_me.php', post_data, function(response){  
                if(response.type == 'error'){ //load json data from server and output message     
                    output = '<div class="error">'+response.text+'</div>';
                }else{
                    output = '<div class="success">'+response.text+'</div>';
                    //reset values in all input fields
                    $("#contact_form  input[required=true], #contact_form textarea[required=true]").val(''); 
                    $("#contact_form #contact_body").slideUp(); //hide form after success
                }
                $("#contact_form #contact_results").hide().html(output).slideDown();
            }, 'json');
        }
    });

    //reset previously set border colors and hide all message on .keyup()
    $("#contact_form  input[required=true], #contact_form textarea[required=true]").keyup(function() { 
        $(this).css('border-color',''); 
        $("#contact_results").slideUp();
    });
});
</script>
```

PHP

```
<?php
if($_POST)
{
    $to_email       = "myemail@gmail.com"; //Recipient email, Replace with own email here
    $from_email     = 'noreply@your_domain.com'; //from mail, it is mandatory with some hosts and without it mail might endup in spam.

    //check if its an ajax request, exit if not
    if(!isset($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) AND strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_X_REQUESTED_WITH']) != 'xmlhttprequest') {

        $output = json_encode(array( //create JSON data
            'type'=>'error', 
            'text' => 'Sorry Request must be Ajax POST'
        ));
        die($output); //exit script outputting json data
    } 

    //Sanitize input data using PHP filter_var().
    $user_name      = filter_var($_POST["user_name"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $user_email     = filter_var($_POST["user_email"], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
    $country_code   = filter_var($_POST["country_code"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $phone_number   = filter_var($_POST["phone_number"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    $subject        = filter_var($_POST["subject"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $message        = filter_var($_POST["msg"], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);

    //additional php validation
    if(strlen($user_name)<4){ // If length is less than 4 it will output JSON error.
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Name is too short or empty!'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){ //email validation
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Please enter a valid email!'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($country_code, FILTER_VALIDATE_INT)){ //check for valid numbers in country code field
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Enter only digits in country code'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(!filter_var($phone_number, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT)){ //check for valid numbers in phone number field
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Enter only digits in phone number'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(strlen($subject)<3){ //check emtpy subject
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Subject is required'));
        die($output);
    }
    if(strlen($message)<3){ //check emtpy message
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Too short message! Please enter something.'));
        die($output);
    }

    //email body
    $message_body = $message."\r\n\r\n-".$user_name."\r\nEmail : ".$user_email."\r\nPhone Number : (".$country_code.") ". $phone_number ;

    //proceed with PHP email.
    $headers = 'From: '. $from_email .'' . "\r\n" .
    'Reply-To: '.$user_email.'' . "\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

    $send_mail = mail($to_email, $subject, $message_body, $headers);

    if(!$send_mail)
    {
        //If mail couldn't be sent output error. Check your PHP email configuration (if it ever happens)
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Could not send mail! Please check your PHP mail configuration.'));
        die($output);
    }else{
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'message', 'text' => 'Hi '.$user_name .' Thank you for your email'));
        die($output);
    }
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using the jQuery `.validate()` plugin?
[jQuery Validator Link](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)

Front end and back end validation are a bit different. On the front end you want to make sure that you're getting the right data types, required fields, etc. and that the form is truly ready to be submitted. On the server side, you want to make sure that you have clean data and that it's going to write to the database properly but you don't generally have to deal with error messages unless something catastrophic happens and the database is unavailable or something.

Comment: I'm having no issues with the front-end validation that I use. 
but, with the PHP back end errors as shown above, I need to refresh to see the cookie and I want it to be set correctly while validating.

Comment: I see what you're getting at. I think you might be best off using `$_SESSION` instead of cookies.

Comment: I agree, but I need to use cookies.